# List all objects in a dataset using bq ls command in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, dataset, bq

I am trying to list all the objects present in a dataset in BigQuery.

I tried using `bq ls projectID:dataset_name` command in Google SDK shell. However this returned only the list of tables present in the dataset. I am interested in listing all the stored procedures present in the same dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get the [list of functions with a query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-routines#routines_view):

```
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql \
'SELECT
   *
 FROM
   mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES'
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to include all routines in the `bq ls` command by setting the flag `--routines=true`:

```bash
bq ls dataset_name --routines=true
```

The default value is `false`. Routines include persistent user-defined functions, table functions (Preview), and stored procedures. See [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_ls) for more detail.